# Ativar/Desativar input ao clicar em um checkbox

Tags: javascript, dom

Tenho este código:

```js
function EnableDisableTextBox(quant_a0) {
  var txtquant_a0 = document.getElementById("quant_a0");
   txtquant_a0.disabled = quant_a0.checked ? false : true;
  if (!txtquant_a0.disabled) {
    txtquant_a0.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
      <p>Tamanho do Cartaz</p>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-md-5">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="tamanhoCartaz[]" value="0" id="customCheck1" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Cartaz A0</label>
      <input type="text" name="quant[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" id="quant_a0" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-md-5">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="tamanhoCartaz[]" value="1" id="customCheck2" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">Cartaz A1</label>
      <input type="text" name="quant[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" id="quant_a1" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-md-5">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="tamanhoCartaz[]" value="2" id="customCheck3" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck3">Cartaz A2</label>
      <input type="text" name="quant[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade"id="quant_a2" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-md-5">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="tamanhoCartaz[]" value="3" id="customCheck4" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck4">Cartaz A3</label>
      <input type="text" name="quant[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" id="quant_a3" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox col-md-5">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="tamanhoCartaz[]" value="4" id="customCheck5" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck5">Cartaz A4</label>
      <input type="text" name="quant[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" id="quant_a4" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
```

A ideia seria fazer ativar/desativar os inputs[text] ao clickar na checkbox

Comment: Por favor, clique em [edit] e melhore o título da sua pergunta. Da forma que está o título não transparece nenhuma informação referente à sua dúvida. A ideia do título é justamente informar o conteúdo da pergunta ao leitor sem que esse necessite acessar a mesma.

Comment: Estava elaborando a resposta quando fecharam a pergunta. Basta trocar sua função por: 
   `function EnableDisableTextBox(element) {
       element.parentElement.querySelector('[id*="quant_"]').disabled = !!element.checked;
    }` e na chamada dela colocar this como parametro:  `onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)`

Comment: Basicamente o código acima vai receber o objeto checkbox e através do pai dele, pegar o  input com id iniciado com quant_ e então mudar o atributo disabled para o mesmo status do checkbox

Comment: Talvez o português da pergunta não seja o habitual, agora marcar como não está claro o suficiente discordo plenamente! O AP quer simplesmente habilitar o input quando a relativa checkbox for marcada. Se não for isso, me considero o mais burro dos seres humanos!!!

Comment: Coloquei a resposta na sua própria pergunta

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Não deve colocar a resposta na pergunta que não é como o site funciona e você certamente sabe isso.  Quem fechou achou que tinha motivos suficientes para tal, e se discorda abra uma pergunta no meta solicitando a reabertura. Lembre-se que todos somos humanos e podemos cometer erros mas pessoalmente acho que a pergunta não está muito clara. Dá a ideia que o objetivo é desativar o campo ao lado do check, mas não dá para ter a certeza pois o autor da pergunta não clarificou. Entretanto sugiro que reverta a sua edição.

Comment: @Isac, antes da edição para mim já estava clara o suficiente, agora então `Ativar/Desativar input ao clicar em um checkbox` nem vou comentar... Mas vou disponibilizar resposta de outra forma.

Comment: Du Santos, você pode ver uma solução neste link http://kithomepage.com/sos/enable-disable-input-with-checkbox.html Depois que vc acessou o link, deixe um cometário para mim para que eu retire ele do ar